# Como mostrar o ID de um usuário através de sessions?

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho o seguinte arquivo para a validação do usuário, e gostaria de mostrar o ID do usuário, apenas a vias de testes, porém não me retorna nada no "menu.php"

validacao.php

```
<?php
// Verifica se houve POST e se o usuário ou a senha é(são) vazio(s)
if (!empty($_POST) AND (empty($_POST['email_login']) OR empty($_POST['senha_login']))) {
    header("Location: index.php"); exit;
}
// Tenta se conectar ao servidor MySQL
$conecta = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or trigger_error(mysql_error());
// Tenta se conectar a um banco de dados MySQL
mysqli_select_db($conecta, 'bdteste') or trigger_error(mysqli_error());
$usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($conecta, $_POST['email_login']);
$senha = mysqli_real_escape_string($conecta, $_POST['senha_login']);
// Validação do usuário/senha digitados
$sql = "SELECT `id_system`, `email_system`, `nome_system` FROM `usr_system` WHERE (`email_system` = '". $usuario ."') AND (`senha_system` = '". $senha ."') LIMIT 1";
$query = mysqli_query($conecta,$sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($query) != 1) {
    // Mensagem de erro quando os dados são inválidos e/ou o usuário não foi encontrado
    echo "Login inválido!";  
} else {
    // Salva os dados encontados na variável $resultado
    $resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

    // Se a sessão não existir, inicia uma
    if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
    $_SESSION["nome"]  = $resultado["nome_system"];
    // Salva os dados encontrados na sessão
    $_SESSION['UsuarioID'] = $resultado['id_system'];
    // Redireciona o visitante
    header("Location: menu.php");
    exit;
}
?>
```

```
    menu.php

    <?php
    session_start();
    // aqui a conexão

    echo "Bem vindo, ".$_SESSION['id_system'];
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá,
Neste trecho você salva duas variáveis na sessão "nome" e "UsuarioID"

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
$_SESSION["nome"]  = $resultado["nome_system"];
// Salva os dados encontrados na sessão
$_SESSION['UsuarioID'] = $resultado['id_system'];
```

Porém no arquivo menu.php, você está tentando acessar esta variável

```
$_SESSION['id_system'].
```

Você pode alterar o nome dessa variável `$_SESSION['UsuarioID']` para `$_SESSION['id_system']` ou acessar `$_SESSION['UsuarioID']` no arquivo menu.

Comment: Oi, fiz o que você disse e saiu o erro de Index Of. Porém não aparece nada! Apenas "Bem Vindo, 1" cmo faço pra aparecer o nome invés d 1?

Comment: Você ja tentou retirar este trecho session_start() do arquivo menu. E deixar apenas no validacao.php?

Comment: Este erro ocorre quando não consegue encontrar o índice no array. Provavelmente seja por você iniciar novamente a sessão no arquivo menu.php

Comment: Tentei agora... não deu certo!

Comment: Qual o retorno?

Comment: Vinius, deu certo, MUITISSIMO obrigado